# Filter out rows based on the current username

Tags: sql, view, restriction

I have a table that needs to be user restricted, and I have thought of two ways of implementing a query that only shows user specific view. One way is for me to cross join each entry to the current user, and the second is including username query as a sub query in where clause. I'm wondering which has the best performance result, or does it not matter?

CROSS JOIN:

```
SELECT quota.username, quota.quota
FROM quota
CROSS JOIN 
    (SELECT nt_username AS [username]
    FROM sys.sysprocesses 
    WHERE spid = @@SPID) o
WHERE quota.username = o.[username]
```

OR

```
SELECT quota.username, quota.quota

FROM quota

WHERE 
    quota.username = 
    (SELECT nt_username
    FROM sys.sysprocesses 
    WHERE spid = @@SPID)
```

thank you for any help and guidance!

Comment: Your cross join should be an inner join.  To see which one performs better, run them a few thousand times and average out the execution time.  Note that the latter can only be done with application code such as .net, php, coldfusion, etc.